# How do you debug an Android app that gives runtime errors after obfuscation with ProGuard?

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

After compiling an Android app with ProGuard I get runtime errors and since the code is obfuscated, I have no idea where the errors are coming from.
The app works fine without ProGuard.
Compiling with ProGuard also works fine.
How do you debug obfuscated code?

Here is how one of the errors looks like:

```
com.facebook.aq: com.facebook.c.f got an unexpected method signature: 
public abstract  java.lang.Object com.facebook.c.c.a(java.lang.String)
at com.facebook.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.c.f.b(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.c.f.invoke(Unknown Source)
at $Proxy0.a(Native Method)
at com.facebook.b.al.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.b.al.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.f.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: Looks like some class tries to access an obfuscated method via reflection, but can't find the method by the name. Which classes inside the com.facebook.abc package could be used by an external library?

Answer (score 0):

Inside proguard output folder there is mappings.

You need first to find what actual class, methods etc are referred with `com.facebook.c.f` and then look at the code.

Does it use reflection? Any string constants referencing classes? etc